# Not able to login in admin panel from Chrome, Firefox, IE

Tags: google-chrome, internet-explorer, magento, firefox, authentication

I have an ecommerce website on latest version of magento and is hosted on godaddy (Shared server).

For some days it was working fine. But now, I am unable to login in my admin panel from all browsers - Chrome, IE, Firefox. I have already tried clearing out my cookies and site preferences but still no resolution. There is no error message. Page just refreshed back to login page.

Can someone please help. Its impacting my business.

Comment: Check your system.log file in var/log directory.

Comment: Did you moved the site from one server to another or upgraded it?

Answer (score 1):

The problem that you are talking about is of cookie problem.If you can log in to your admin panel then go to

> "System->Configuration->Web"

Under "Session Cookie Management" You will see the field for "Cookie Domain", add your domain there for your case ".com" save and try login again.If doesnot work try putting "/" on "cookie path".

If you cannot login to your admin panel then you have to edit it in "core_config_data" table. In that table just search for the field mentioned above and than make changes.

Hope this will work.

Answer (score 0):

This what I do when encountered that kind of problem:

1. go to your database using phpmyadmin edit the core_config_data
   search for web/unsecure/base_url and web/secure/base_url
   edit the value with your current domain name.
2. go to your magento root folder 
   delete all the files inside the var/cache
   delete all the files inside the var/session